# How to install tcl/tk on python 3.5?

Tags: python-3.x, tcl, linux-mint

I've recently installed from python.org `python 3.5`, since Package Manager doesn't support new version. I've installed `pip` and other packages by it, but when I checked `matplotlib.pyplot`, I got errors, and it also cannot import `tkinter`. As I checked it is because `tkinter` is supported by some other application (ActiveTCL).

But I couldn't install it: downloaded from here http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads the package, and run `sudo ./install.sh` (bash file in the package), it show some GUI, installed, but nothing chaged for python.

And for some reason on all questinons all the answers are like: run

`sudo apt-get install python3-tk`

But it doesn't work for 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply wrong. Linux Mint 18 has Python 3.5; if you want to upgrade your Python version, you **really** should just upgrade to Mint18; Python is central to **a lot of software** so simply installing a new version of it won't work with the old packages from apt-get, and is a recipe for disaster.

Note that the reason why we have Linux distros in the first place is to offer coherent package archives, ie. any Mint package using Python was built for *exactly* the python used in your current Mint release. If you now install python3-tk from a package, it is also meant to work with the Python from Mint, not the Python you've installed separately.

Whenever you have two versions of the same library/framework, one from your distro, one from your local installation, you're running into the risk of conflicts and earn the job of building **every** software that should use your newer library/framework version yourself. This is tiresome, and, again, the reason you have linux distros that do that for you.

Comment: It is great news, I didn't knew about it. I perfectly understand that package manager file work only for its own apps. Why you thought otherwise? And question is quite straightforward, even if mint 18 support 3.5, in the future will be made new python, which won't be supported by mint 18, and so on. So it is best to know how to do this kind of things.

Comment: the point is "how to do these things" is: building a separate prefix for your non-distro versions, and keep everything separate. It's not something you usually do. Whenever you have two versions of the same library/framework, one from your distro, one from your local installation, you're running into the risk of conflicts and earn the job of building **every** software that should use your newer library/framework version yourself. This is tiresome, and, again, the reason you have linux distros that do that for you.

Comment: It's not what is usually done, but knowledge how it can be done is useful.

Comment: well, there you have it: python's TK bindings need to be rebuilt from source by you. How to do that always depends on the software you're rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `ActiveTcl 8.6`, (re)install `Python 3.5` and install `Matplotlib 1.5.3`.

The key point is the reconfiguration of Python after the installation of ActiveTcl.

Let's do it step by step.

Install `ActiveTcl` as usual

```
cd path/to/activetcl
bash install.sh
```

Let us assume that you have installed ActiveTcl in folder `/opt/ActiveTcl-8.6` (the default installer choice).

You should configure and install `Python` as follows:

```
cd path/to/python

./configure --with-ensurepip --with-tcltk-includes='-I/opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/include' 
   --with-tcltk-libs='/opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/lib/libtcl8.6.so /opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/lib/libtk8.6.so'

./make
./make test
./make install
```

Verify that the configuration is correct importing the `tkinter` module in the Python shell

```
>>> import tkinter
```

Finally install `Matplotlib` as usual

```
cd path/to/matplotlib
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Comment: You might be able to get away with just running `sudo update-python-modules -a` instead of reinstalling python 3.5